# How to set vector type field as a secondary index in smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, index

I want to set a group vector as a secondary index in the user smart contract. **group** is the list of groups.
Following is the changes I am doing:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] usertable {
                        name key;
                        std::string username;
                        std::string contact;
                        std::vector<name> group;

                        uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value;}
                        uint64_t get_secondary_1() const { return group[value];}
                };

                typedef eosio::multi_index<"users"_n, usertable,indexed_by<"bygroup"_n, const_mem_fun<usertable, std::vector<name>, &usertable::get_secondary_1>>> user_index;
```

Its giving error

> error: value of type 'uint64_t (user::usertable::*)() const' is not
>   implicitly convertible to 'std::__1::vector > (user::usertable::*)() const'
>                   typedef eosio::multi_index<"users"_n, usertable,indexed_by<"bygroup"_n, const_mem_fun, &usertable::get_secondary_1>>> user_index;

I am not getting exactly how to give a vector of name type list as a secondary index. Please help and guide.

Comment: where's the value

Comment: Do you want to search for an item with an arbitrary value in vector `group`? eosio allows only 5 types of secondary indices: uint64_t, uint128_t, checksum256, double, long double.

Comment: I have list of group id's (in vector) which are in string format, and want to set the vector as secondary indices.

Comment: @conr2d So, according to your comment, I cannot set a vector as a secondary indice!

Comment: No, you can't. There can be some indirect ways to doing this, but its implementation would vary according to requirements. (The number of items in vector or the number of kinds of items, etc.)

Comment: Okay @conr2d thanx for the suggestion.